# Function of finding average of subjects

Tags: c, function

```
#include<stdio.h>

float avg(float x,float y,float z)

{
    
float avg=(x+y+z)/3;
    
 printf("average=%f",avg);

};

void main()

{
float phy,chem,bio;

 printf("enter physics marks");

 scanf("%f ",&phy);

printf("\n enter chemistry marks");

 scanf("%f ",&chem);


 printf("\n enter biology marks");

 scanf("%f ",&bio);

 avg(phy,chem,bio);

}
```

This program is find the average of three subject by the functions. But ,whenever I run this program it takes one extra value after giving input for physics variable.

What is the reason  behind  this problem  and how do I solve this?

Comment: You need to provide the program

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre].

Comment: `float avg=(x+y+z)/2;` - 2 should be 3

Comment: Corrected that mistake.

Answer (score 1):

### Incorrect main definition:

The correct definition of the main function is either:

```
int main(void)
```

Or

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

The rest are either extensions or outdated, and do not conform to the standard.

### OP's problem:

> Average, which is the arithmetic mean, and is calculated by adding a group of numbers and then dividing by the count of those numbers.

Change:

```
float avg=(x+y+z)/2;
```

to

```
float avg = (x + y + z) / 3;
```

**Unrelated:**

Use `double` instead of float. The function `scanf` returns the number of elements it has successfully processed and assigned. Check for it.

Comment: I changed data type from float to double and change the definition of main as you given. But it doesn't work.

Comment: It works just fine on my system once I remove the extra whitespace in the calls to scanf. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19499060/what-is-the-effect-of-trailing-white-space-in-a-scanf-format-string

Comment: Thank you Haris . It works now

Comment: @Geek Anytime. Consider accepting the answer if you find it helpful.